# Data Cleaning Philosophy - Source, Data Warehouse, or Front-end?

Tags: mysql, mapping, tableau-api, data-warehouse, data-cleaning

I'm in a traditional Back to Front ETL stack from a data source (Adobe Analytics) to MySQL data warehouse to a Tableau front end for visualization.  My question revolves around best practices for cleaning data / mapping and at what step.
1) Cleaning: We have no automated (SSIS, etc.) connector from the source (Adobe) to the data warehouse so we're left with periodic uploading of CSV files.  For various reasons these files become less than optimal (misspellings, nulls, etc.) Question: should the 'cleaning' be done to the CSV files, or once the data is uploaded into MySQL data warehouse (in tables/views)?
2) Mapping: a number of different end user use cases require us to map the data to tables (geographic regions, type of accounts, etc.)... should this be done in the data warehouse (MySQL joins) or is it just as good in the front end (Tableau)? The real question pertains to performance, I believe, as you could do it relatively easily in either step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) **Cleaning**: I'd advise you to load the data in the CSV files into a [staging database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_(data)) and clean it from there, before it reaches the database to which you connect Tableau to. This way you can keep the original files, which you can eventually reload if necessary. I'm not sure what a "traditional Back to Front ETL stack" is, but an ETL tool like Microsoft SSIS or Pentaho Data Integrator (free) will be a valuable help with building these processes, and you could then run your ETL jobs periodically or every time a new file is uploaded to the directory. Here is a good example of such a process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014/integration-services/lesson-1-create-a-project-and-basic-package-with-ssis

2) "**Mapping**": You should have a data model, probably a [dimensional model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_modeling), built on the database that Tableau connects to. This data model should store clean and "business modelled" data. You should perform the lookups (joins/mappings) when you are Transforming your data, so you can Load it into the data model. Having Tableau explore a dimensional model of clean data will also be better for UX/performance.

The overall flow would look something like: CSV -> Staging database -> Clean/Transform/Map -> Business data model (database) -> Tableau